# Swift type inference discrepancy when inside initializer

Tags: swift, type-inference

In the following snippet

```
class T {}
var dummy : Int = Int.init()
class S : T{
    override init () {
        super.init()
        var dummy2 : () = Int.init()
    }
}
```

the type of `dummy` is `Int`, but the type of `dummy2` is `()`.

How come their types be different if they are inferred from equal expressions?

Comment: This code doesn't compile for me. `Int.init()` is an `Int`.

Comment: @jtbandes I don't have Xcode to test with, but I'm toying with Swift via online compilers. Both runswiftlang.com and swiftstub.com seem to refuse to compile if `dummy2` is annotated with type `Int`.

Comment: Ah. Well it works in Swift 2 :)

Comment: Ok, I see. Perhaps you want to write a proper answer so we can close this question, then? Thanks.

Comment: Your code gives the following error in XCode: Int is not convertible to ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a Swift 1/1.2 issue only. In Swift 2, `Int.init()` correctly returns an `Int` and so `dummy2` must be an Int.